# Update all rows to 0 and only one to 1

Tags: sql, sql-update

How can I update all rows at 0 and only where the id=x to set 1.

```
UPDATE car_ads 
SET deal_of_the_week_p = IF(deal_of_the_week_p = 1, 0, 1) 
WHERE ad_id = 999
```

Now i have something like that but is not working.

Thanks

Comment: what type of SQL is this? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sir Please try this `UPDATE car_ads 
    SET deal_of_the_week_p = IF(deal_of_the_week_p = "1", "0", "1") 
    WHERE ad_id = 999`

Comment: and please at list told us what it mean not working?

Comment: `IF` is invalid (standard) SQL. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a standards-compliant DBMS, you could use

`UPDATE car_ads
SET deal_of_the_week_p = CASE WHEN ad_id = 999 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Alternatively, it could be run as 2 separate updates -

`UPDATE car_ads
SET deal_of_the_week_p = 0`

`UPDATE car_ads
SET deal_of_the_week_p = 1
WHERE ad_id = 999`

Comment: You are the best :) this is exactly what I needed and is working :